# Restrict IP access to Wordpress microsite via .htaccss

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

I am using Wordpress multisite and would like to use an .htaccess directive to block access to certain IPs. e.g.

```
order deny, allow
deny from 255.0.0.0
allow from all
```

This is easy to do if each Wordpress installation is in it's own vhost but WP multisite uses a single WP installation in a single vHost to server a bunch of different sites. That means the .htaccess file would be shared.

What else can I add to the .htaccess file to make certain directives applicable to certain microsites only?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your Microsite is using a single WP installation you can solve the problem by using WordPress Plugin. Here is a plugin through which you can block the IP address as you like.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ban/

Comment: Thanks Anoop, I had checked out WP Ban a while ago and it didn't suite my needs. I need to block specific U.S. States and WP Ban is just individual IPs or countries. I've since created my own plugin to solve the issue.

Comment: Hi Kristin, glad that it helped you :-)